# Ionic 2 : What happens during splash screen?

Tags: android, ios, performance, ionic2, profiling

I build an Ionic 2 app and I want to know what precisly happens during the app splash screen ?

Can you advise me about efficient profiling tools to analyse all performance of my app, even during this splash screen ?

My app, in production mode, is initialize in 6 seconds (Honor 6x pro). I think is too much, what do you think ?

Thanks for you help !

My config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.myapp722890" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>MyApp</name>
  <description>Mobile version of MyApp</description>
  <author email="my mail" href="https://toto/">toto</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://my-ip:8100"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300"/>
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="500"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~2.0.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-base64-to-gallery" spec="~4.1.2"/>
  <plugin name="mx.ferreyra.callnumber" spec="~0.0.2"/>
  <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

My platform.ready function :

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide(); 
    });
```

Comment: I don't know ionic but isn't it you who write code for what happens during splash screen in ionic?

Comment: No it's not me. I think initialize plugins and components but I'm not sure.

Comment: Many people generally keep a delay in splash screen to make it appear for some time. check if you wrote any delays

Comment: Sure. In a config file I have a delay of 3000 ms. But my splash screen stay during more than 6000 ms. I will try to delete the default delay.

Answer (score 0):

Building using `ionic build android --prod` does the trick. It reduces the initialize time of the app greatly.

Comment: I already do that. In fact it reduce time greatly on my android device : 14sec to 6 sec. But I want to find why I keep this 6 secondes.

Comment: I think it depends on your platform.ready code. Maybe you can post it here so I can take a look at it.

Comment: can you post your config.xml file here?

Comment: My platform.ready : StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();